# Bootstrap 5 - Insert datetime picker

Tags: accessibility, bootstrap-5

I'm using bootstrap 5.0.
Is there a way to insert a datetimepicker? I've found many datetimepicker but they are not accessible. Or how can i get date and time from the user in accessible way?

Thanks

Comment: `<input type="date">`  just use the custom [date input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date) , this should be accessible. If you can't find a solution that fits your need, code your own.

Comment: Bootstrap does not have a built-in datepicker, and just adding `<input type="date">` doesn't produce an accessible result. I have not been able to find anything worthwhile that doesn't require jQuery, which is really unfortunate. Dequeue has a pretty good implementation that works well for me: https://dequeuniversity.com/library/aria/date-picker